# removing array duplicates without using method

Tags: java

Hello Can you please help me in resolving duplicates from array.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] arr = {"Barcelona","Watford","Manchester United","Real Mandrid","Barcelona","Machester United","city"};
        int[] arraya = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1,11 }; // input array
        int L = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            System.out.print("  " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n" );

        for (int i = 0; i < (L- 1) ; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < L; j++) {
                if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]));{
                    arr[j] = arr[L -1];
                    L--;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            System.out.print("  " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting the expected answer and the array deleted the unique values also.

Comment: the output what i am getting is Barcelona  city  Barcelona

Comment: From which array you want to remove duplicates.

Comment: arr or arraya???

Comment: Time to debug ...

Comment: As a suggestion: Use a `Set`. Makes your life easier.

Comment: It's probably here `if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]));{` see the extra `;`? Get rid of that for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] arr = {"Barcelona","Watford","Manchester United","Real Mandrid","Barcelona","Manchester United","city"};
        int L = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();     

        for (int i = 0; i < L - 1 ; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < L; j++) {
                if(arr[i].equals(arr[j])){
                    arr[j] = arr[L -1];
                    L--;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++){
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();   
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Barcelona Watford Manchester United Real Mandrid Barcelona Manchester United city
Barcelona Watford Manchester United Real Mandrid city
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` it will remove the duplication.
To convert an array to `set` just use this :

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `;` after this `if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]))`
I think if you remove it, your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. The semicolon was the reason for the error.